# wordpress on localhost can't automatically direct to index

Tags: php, apache

I have installed apache.php.mysql.phpmyadmin separately,not used wamp or xampp.

And now I put wordpress in htdocs.

They works but somehow when I browse localhost/wordpress/, it can't automatically direct to the login page or /wordpress/wp-admin/index.php

(I remember it can in normal situation)

picture of what http://localhost/wordpress shows

[image]

phpmyadmin is also in this situation.

I guess someing wrong with the setting of mysql or php,but I can't figure out.

update: problem solved!

Comment: are you sure php is enabled? most of the time when you see this the index.php is not loaded because php is disabled.

Comment: you have a problems with Aapche setup, more like mod-rewrite is not enabled, please check/update question with your configs

Comment: Are you sure the rewrite mod is enable with apache? Maybe there's a need to set a special port, like localhost:8888 and another port for MySQL?

Comment: thanks! I allow the rewirte mod and it works!
I follow the steps in this website:
https://www.badprog.com/windows-7-installing-php-apache-http-mysql-phpmyadmin-on-windows